# Cannot insert data into mySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP and having a hard time inserting data into my mySQL database using PHP. PHP is working and the connection appears fine. Thanks for the help, here's my code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","USER_DATA");

if(!$conn)
{
        echo "Error connecting to DB";
        echo "Debug errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
}
else
{
        echo "Connected successfully!";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `login` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'rrrrrdfbdfgv', $
$result->query($sql);




?>
```

Comment: I think that you may not have copied everything. Your query is missing a part.

Comment: You are missing some code there, please update your question with your full source for `$sql = ...`. Also if you are just learning you should learn `PDO`

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), which will provide any errors that MySQL is throwing. That way you're not working blind.

Comment: Thanks for the tips all. Why would it be better to learn PDO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","USER_DATA");

if(!$conn)
{
        echo "Error connecting to DB";
        echo "Debug errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
}
else
{
        echo "Connected successfully!";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `login` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('rrrrrdfbdfgv', $password)";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);    
?>
```

add your `id` to `autoincrement` in database and also give `primary key`

Here code which can helps you. :)

Comment: Presumably `id` is auto-incrementing already since `NULL` is being used there.

Comment: Yes but i just give a example if wants to use NULL than he will use

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I did have auto-increment but I appreciate the reminder to check.